# undefined reference to boost::program_options in vowpalwabbit compilation, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, boost-program-options, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install [vowpal_wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) in ubuntu 16.04.

Error :

```
./libvw.a(search.o): In function `Search::setup(vw&)':
search.cc:(.text+0xa5f8): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
search.cc:(.text+0xaafe): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
search.cc:(.text+0xac0e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
search.cc:(.text+0xad20): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
search.cc:(.text+0xadda): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
search.cc:(.text+0xae94): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
./libvw.a(search.o):search.cc:(.text+0xafaa): more undefined references to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const' follow
./libvw.a(search_meta.o): In function `SelectiveBranchingMT::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_meta.cc:(.text+0x7645): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./libvw.a(search_sequencetask.o): In function `SequenceSpanTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_sequencetask.cc:(.text+0x14ab): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./libvw.a(search_sequencetask.o): In function `ArgmaxTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_sequencetask.cc:(.text+0x2a02): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./libvw.a(search_dep_parser.o): In function `DepParserTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_dep_parser.cc:(.text+0x4328): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./libvw.a(search_dep_parser.o): In function `void Search::check_option<unsigned int>(unsigned int&, vw&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, char const*, bool, bool (*)(unsigned int, unsigned int), char const*, char const*)':
search_dep_parser.cc:(.text._ZN6Search12check_optionIjEEvRT_R2vwRN5boost15program_options13variables_mapEPKcbPFbS1_S1_ESA_SA_[_ZN6Search12check_optionIjEEvRT_R2vwRN5boost15program_options13variables_mapEPKcbPFbS1_S1_ESA_SA_]+0x1ea): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
./libvw.a(search_entityrelationtask.o): In function `EntityRelationTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_entityrelationtask.cc:(.text+0x33f7): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./libvw.a(search_graph.o): In function `GraphTask::initialize(Search::search&, unsigned long&, boost::program_options::variables_map&)':
search_graph.cc:(.text+0x17aa): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
search_graph.cc:(.text+0x196c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
./libvw.a(scorer.o): In function `scorer_setup(vw&)':
scorer.cc:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
scorer.cc:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'vw' failed
make[1]: *** [vw] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kapil/Projects/MachineLearning/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'vw' failed
make: *** [vw] Error 2
```

I am following the instructions provided in the repository. I have installed `libboost-program-options-dev`, `zlib1g-dev` & `libboost-python-dev`. I tried to first run just `make`, which gives undefined reference error. Then I tried using `autogen.sh` script before `make`, but that leads to same error too. I also tried, unsuccessfully, using commands like `make BOOST_FLAGS=-lboost-program-options` & `make BOOST_FLAGS=-lboost_options`. I tried using `clang++` but that gives same output. I have checked for both `boost` & `boost_program-options` & they are present and are the latest version. How do I remove the error?

The problem is that, although I can install vowpalwabbit using ppa in ubuntu, when I try installing it for python using pip, it gives the same reference error. I need to install the python version.

Comment: did you add -lboost_options to the linker command line?

Comment: where should I add that? The makefile isn't mine so please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you're getting indicate you don't have `libboost` development libraries (more specifically, `libboost-program-options-dev`) installed. `libboost-program-options-dev` is listed in the prerequisites for building `vw` from source.  You may install *all* the boost libraries+headers by installing the meta package `libboost-all-dev`.

According to the [official instructions in the README.md file](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/README.md) there's no need to run `autogen.sh` on Ubuntu (in fact, it is recommended ***not*** to do it by default because it overwrites the original `Makefile`s which work just fine).

Here are the full Ubuntu instructions (reproduced from the official wiki on github for convenience):

### Ubuntu/Debian specific info

On Ubuntu/Debian/Mint and similar the following sequence should work for building the latest from github:

### Get libboost program-options and zlib:

```
apt-get install libboost-program-options-dev zlib1g-dev
```

### Get the python libboost bindings (python subdir) - optional:

```
apt-get install libboost-python-dev
```

### Get the vw source:

```
git clone git://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git
```

### Build:

```
cd vowpal_wabbit
make
make test       # (optional)
make install
```

If these instructions don't work for you, please make sure you don't have other, non-standard changes to your environment. Changes that are known to cause issues are non-standard `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_RPRELOAD`, or `ldconfig` changes which might cause the linker to fail to find libraries in the standard places.